# konacha - helper methods coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, chai, konacha

I'm trying to define a helper method in konacha in coffeescript, something like this

```
@expect_int_is_universal = (i) ->
  expect(i).to.equal 42

describe '#test', ->
  it 'checks if integer is 42', ->
      @expect_int_is_universal(42)
```

Is it possible in konacha?

edit: error log here:

[image]

update: the fix is putting it inside a beforeEach block

```
beforeEach ->
  @expect_int_is_universal = (i) ->
    expect(i).to.equal 42

describe '#test', ->
  it 'checks if integer is 42', ->
      @expect_int_is_universal(42)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `@` (AKA `this`) inside your `it` callback is not the same `@` as at the top level so you're defining `expect_int_is_universal` as a method on one object but trying to call it as a method on another object. Try without the `@`s. I don't know enough Konocha, Mocha, or Chai to say any more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mu is too short hasn't successfully converted his comment as the answer, but i'll provide it here below:

@ (AKA this) inside your it callback is not the same @ as at the top level so you're defining expect_int_is_universal as a method on one object but trying to call it as a method on another object. Try without the @s. I don't know enough Konocha, Mocha, or Chai to say any more than that